# How to get hyper parameters in nested cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

I have read the following posts for nested cross validation and still am not 100% sure what I am to do with model selection with nested cross validation:

- [Nested cross validation for model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/nested-cross-validation-for-model-selection/65156#65156)
- [Model selection and cross-validation: The right way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64991/model-selection-and-cross-validation-the-right-way?rq=1)

To explain my confusion, let me try to walk through the model selection with nested cross validation method step by step.

1. Create an outer CV loop with K-Fold. This will be used to estimate the performance of the hyper-parameters that "won" each inner CV loops.
2. Use GridSearchCV to create an inner CV loop where in each inner loop, GSCV goes through all possible combinations of the parameter space and comes up with the best set of parameters.
3. After GSCV found the best parameters in the inner loop, it is tested with the test set in the outer loop to get an estimation of performance.
4. The outer loop then updates to the next fold as the test set and the rest as training set, and 1-3 repeats. Total possible "winning" parameters are number of folds designated in the outer loop. So if the outer loop is 5 folds, then you will have a performance estimation of an algorithm with **5 different sets** of hyper parameters, **NOT** the performance of one particular set of hyper parameters.

This approach is illustrated on SKLearn's example page:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html

**Question:**
After **4.**, how do you determine which hyper parameters worked the best? I understand that you want to train your algorithm (e.g. Logistic Regression, Random Forest, etc.) with the COMPLETE data set at the end. But how do you determine which hyper parameters worked the best in your nested cross validation? My understanding is that for each inner loop, a different set of hyper parameters will win. And for the outer loop, you are getting an estimation of your GridSearchCV performance, but you are not getting any one particular set of hyper parameters. So, in the final model creation, how do you know what hyper parameters to use? That's the missing logic I have trouble understanding from other treads.

Thank you in advance for any tips, especially if @Dikran Marsupial and @cbeleites can chime in!

**Edit:** If you can, please in your answer use terms like "algorithm" and "hyper parameters". I think one source of confusion for me is when people use the term "model" or "model selection". I get confused whether they are talking about selecting which algorithm to use or what hyper parameters to use.

**Edit 2:** I have created a [notebook](https://github.com/rosscleung/Projects/blob/b9abc20db545d9f483e90a9b046ea50c74f25718/Tutorial%20notebooks/Nested%20Cross%20Validation%20Example.ipynb) that shows two ways of doing nested cross validation. First way is the one shown in the SKLearn example, and another longer way is one that I wrote. **The way shown in SKLearn doesn't expose the "winning" hyperparameters, but my longer way does.** But the question remains the same. After I have completed the nested cross validation, even with the hyperparameters exposed, what do I do now? As you can see from the hyperparameters at the end of the notebook, they vary quite a bit.

Comment: +1 for the notebook. This question is of interest to me as well and will follow up.

Answer (score 10):

(I'm sure I wrote most of this already in some answer - but can't find it right now. If anyone stumbles across that answer, please link it).
I see 2 slightly different approaches here, which I think are both sensible.

But first some terminology:

- Coming from an applied field, a **(fitted/trained) model** for me is a ready-to-use. I.e. the model contains *all* information needed to generate predictions for new data. Thus, the *model contains* also the *hyperparameters*. As you will see, this point of view is closely related to approach 2 below.
- OTOH, **training algorithm** in my experience is not well defined in the following sense: in order to get the (fitted) model, not only the - let's call it "primary fitting" - of the "normal" model parameters needs to be done, but also the hyperparameters need to be fixed. From my application perspective, there isn't really much difference between parameters and hyperparamers: both are part of *the model*, and need to be estimated/decided during training.
  I guess the difference between them is related to the difference between someone developing new training algorithms who'd usually describe a class of training algorithms together with some steering parameters (the **hyperparameters**) which are difficult/impossibe to fix (or at least to fix how they should be decided/estimated) without application/domain knowledge.

### Approach 1: require stable optimization results

With this approach, "model training" is the fitting of the "normal" model parameters, and *hyperparameters* are given. An inner e.g. cross validation takes care of the hyperparameter optimization.

The crucial step/assumption here to solve the dilemma of whose hyperparameter set should be chosen is to **require the optimization to be stable**. Cross validation for validation purposes assumes that all surrogate models are sufficiently similar to the *final* model (obtained by the same training algorithm applied to the whole data set) to allow treating them as equal (among themselves as well as to the final model). If this assumption breaks down and

1. the surrogate models are still equal (or equivalent) among themselves but not to the final model, we are talking about the well-known pessimistic bias of cross validation.
2. If also the surrogate model are not equal/equivalent to each other, we have problems with *instability*.

For the optimization results of the inner loop this means that **if the optimization is stable, there is no conflict in choosing hyperparameters**. And **if considerable variation is observed across the inner cross validation results, the optimization is not stable**. Unstable training situations have far worse problems than just the decision which of the hyperparameter sets to choose, and I'd really recommend to step back in that case and start the 
modeling process all over.

There's an exception, here, though: there may be several local minima in the optimization yielding equal performance for practical purposes. Requiring also the choice among them to be stable may be an unnecessary strong requirement - but I don't know how to get out of this dilemma.

**Note that if not all models yield the same winning parameter set, you should not use outer loop estimates as generalization error here:**

- If you claim generalization error for parameters $p$, all surrogate models entering into the validation should actually use exactly these parameters.
  (Imagine someone told you they did a cross validation on model with C = 1 and linear kernel and you find out some splits were evaluated with rbf kernel!)
- But unless there is no decision involved as all splits yielded the same parameters, this will break independence in the outer loop: the test data of each split already entered the decision which parameter set wins as it was training data in all other splits and thus used to optimize the parameters.

### Approach 2: treat hyperparameter tuning as part of the model training

This approach bridges the perspectives of the "training algorithm developer" and applied user of the training algorithm.

The training algorithm developer provides a "naked" training algorithm `model = train_naked (trainingdata, hyperparameters)`. As the applied user needs  `tunedmodel = train_tuned (trainingdata)` which also takes care of fixing the hyperparameters.

`train_tuned` can be implemented e.g. by wrapping a cross validation-based optimizer around the naked training algorithm `train_naked`.

`train_tuned` can then be used like any other training algorithm that does not require hyperparameter input, e.g. its output `tunedmodel` can be subjected to cross validation.  Now the hyperparameters are checked for their stability just like the "normal" parameters should be checked for stability as part of the evaluation of the cross validation.

**This is actually what you do and evaluate in the nested cross validation if you average performance of all winning models regardless of their individual parameter sets.**

---

### What's the difference?

We possibly end up with different final models taking those 2 approaches:

- the final model in approach 1 will be `train_naked (all data, hyperparameters from optimization)`
- whereas approach 2 will use `train_tuned (all data)` and - as that runs the hyperparameter optimization again on the larger data set - this may end up with a different set of hyperparameters.

But again the same logic applies: if we find that the final model has substantially different parameters from the cross validation surrogate models, that's a symptom of assumption 1 being violated. So IMHO, again we do not have a conflict but rather a check on whether our (implicit) assumptions are justified. And if they aren't, we anyways should not bet too much on having a good estimate of the performance of that final model.

---

I have the impression (also from seeing the number of similar questions/confusions here on CV) that many people think of nested cross validation doing approach 1. 
But generalization error is usually estimated according to approach 2, so that's the way to go for the final model as well.

---

## Iris example

**Summary:** The optimization is basically pointless. The available sample size does not allow distinctions between the performance of any of the parameter sets here.

From the application point of view, however, the conclusion is that it doesn't matter which of the 4 parameter sets you choose - which isn't all that bad news: you found a comparatively stable plateau of parameters. Here comes the advantage of the proper nested validation of the tuned model: while you're not able to claim that the it is the optimal model, your're still able to claim that the model built on the whole data using  approach 2 will have about 97 % accuracy (95 % confidence interval for 145 correct out of 150 test cases: 92 - 99 %)

Note that also approach 1 isn't as far off as it seems - see below: your optimization accidentally missed a comparatively clear "winner" because of ties (that's actually another very telltale symptom of the sample size problem).

While I'm not deep enough into SVMs to "see" that C = 1 should be a good choice here, I'd go with the more restrictive linear kernel. Also, as you *did* the optimization, there's nothing wrong with choosing the winning parameter set even if you are aware that all parameter sets lead to practically equal performance.

In future, however, consider whether your experience yields rough guesstimates of what performance you can expect and roughly what model would be a good choice. Then build that model (with manually fixed hyperparameters) and calculate a confidence interval for its performance. Use this to decide whether trying to optimize is sensible at all. (I may add that I'm mostly working with data where getting 10 more independent cases is not easy - if you are in a field with large independent sample sizes, things look much better for you)

long version:

As for the example results on the `iris` data set. `iris` has 150 cases, SVM with a grid of 2 x 2 parameters (2 kernels, 2 orders of magnitude for the penalty `C`) are considered.

The inner loop has splits of 129 (2x) and 132 (6x) cases. 
The "best" parameter set is undecided between linear or rbf kernel, both with C = 1. However, the inner test accuracies are *all* (including the always loosing C = 10) within 94 - 98.5 % observed accuracy. The largest difference we have in one of the splits is 3 vs. 8 errors for rbf with C = 1 vs. 10.

There's no way this is a significant difference. I don't know how to extract the predictions for the individual cases in the CV, but even assuming that the 3 errors were shared, and the C = 10 model made additional 5 errors:

```
> table (rbf1, rbf10)
         rbf10
rbf1      correct wrong
  correct     124     5
  wrong         0     3

> mcnemar.exact(rbf1, rbf10)

    Exact McNemar test (with central confidence intervals)

data:  rbf1 and rbf10
b = 5, c = 0, p-value = 0.0625
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
```

Remember that there are 6 pairwise comparisons in the 2 x 2 grid, so we'd need to correct for multiple comparisons as well.

---

#### Approach 1

In 3 of the 4 outer splits where rbf "won" over the linear kernel, they actually had the same estimated accuracy (I guess min in case of ties returns the first suitable index).

Changing the grid to 
`params = {'kernel':['linear', 'rbf'],'C':[1,10]}`
yields

```
({'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 1}, 0.95238095238095233, 0.97674418604651159)
({'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 1}, 0.95238095238095233, 0.98449612403100772)
({'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 1}, 1.0, 0.97727272727272729)
({'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 1}, 0.94444444444444442, 0.98484848484848486)
({'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 1}, 0.94444444444444442, 0.98484848484848486)
({'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 1}, 1.0, 0.98484848484848486)
({'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 1}, 1.0, 0.96212121212121215)
```

### Approach 2:

Here, `clf` is your final model. With `random_state = 2`, rbf with C = 1 wins:

```
In [310]: clf.grid_scores_
[...snip warning...]
Out[310]: 
[mean: 0.97333, std: 0.00897, params: {'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 1},
 mean: 0.98000, std: 0.02773, params: {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 1},
 mean: 0.96000, std: 0.03202, params: {'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 10},
 mean: 0.95333, std: 0.01791, params: {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 10}]
```

(happens about 1 in 5 times, 1 in 6 times `linear` and `rbf` with `C = 1` are tied on rank 1)

Comment: Thanks @cbeleites! I read your answers in other threads too and I was hoping you'd answer my question. Your answer is very in depth but what my question is really focused on is how to analyze the results of a nested CV; I'm still a little unclear as to "what to do after I do nested CV".

Can you take a look at the notebook I created (near the end of my post) and in layman's term explain what to do since two different sets of hyperparameters have been identified as optimal in a nested CV? It's a very very short notebook, I promise!

Comment: @HeavyBreathing I've read the answer, and I'm still not that clear about 'what to do after I do nested CV'. Have you clearly figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question and the answer above 2 times (1st time 3 month ago). I'm interested and also want to find the absolute appropriate way to do cross-validation for my data. After a lot of thinking & reading, it seems that I find the holes and here is my fix:

> To explain my confusion, let me try to walk through the model selection with nested cross validation method step by step.
>
> 1. Create an outer CV loop with K-Fold. This will be used to estimate the performance of the hyper-parameters that "won" each inner CV loops.
> 2. Use GridSearchCV to create an inner CV loop where in each inner loop, GSCV goes through all possible combinations of the parameter space and comes up with the best set of parameters. **(Note: here I assume: data for inner loop = training data for outer loop. You may ask: why ? Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228735/scikit-learn-gridsearchcv-with-multiple-repetitions/42230764#42230764 read the answer section by Vivek Kumar step 4)**
> 3. After GSCV found the "best parameters" in the inner loop (let's call it inner winner), it is tested with the test set in the outer loop to get an estimation of performance (let's call it outer_fold_score1).
> 4. **The outer loop then updates to the next fold as the test set and the rest as training set (to evaluate the "inner winner" on outer loop), the "inner winner" is tested again with the new test set (outer_fold_score2). Then again the outer loop updates to the next fold until the loop is completed. Scores from each fold (outer_fold_score 1,2..) will be average to get the score of the "inner winner" for the outer loop (outer_score)**
> 5. **The outer loop then updates to the next fold as the test set and the rest as training set (to find the next "inner winner" , and 1- 4** repeats *(note that when we repeat 1 we don't create the new K-fold but we use the same outer Kfold every time)*. With each of 1-4 cycle, we get a "best parameters" (or "inner winner") with an outer_score. The one with the best outer_score will be the winner of the winners

Reasoning:

- Basically your question concerns that there are many "winning parameters" for the outer loop. The thing is u didn't complete the outer loop to evaluate and find the "outer winner". Your 4th step only evaluate the "inner winner" in 1 fold in the outer loop, but u didn't "loop it". Therefore I need to replace it with my 4th step - "loop" the evaluation step in the outer loop and get the outer score (by averaging)
- Your 5th step did do the "looping" job in the outer loop, but it's just for building another "inner winner". It didn't loop the "evaluation" of this "inner winner" in the outer loop

Comment: Does this really answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You do **not use nested cross validation to select the hyper parameters** of the algorithm, this method is used for estimating the generalisation error of your **model building procedure**. Where by model building procedure I intend all the steps you applied to reach the final model you are going to be using on field.
A model building procedure could be composed by **the rules** you applied to decide which preprocessing to apply to the data, which feature to use and finally which hyper parameters to use. Think of this as a sort of "meta-algorithm" that receives as input a particular dataset $D$ and produces as output an "algorithm", composed of a **fixed** set of preprocessing transformations, features and finally hyper parameters values.

For example let's say you have  $X , y$ as design matrix and target and you want to train a classifier:
 1. that uses only the first $x$ features in $X$ that have highest correlation with $y$.
 2. you choose the hyper parameters values by minimisation of a 10-fold cross validation error estimate.

If you apply these two step to a particular pair of $X', y'$ you will obtain a specific algorithm with a definite set of features and fixed hyper parameters which will not necessarily be the same of the one you would obtain for $X, y$ although the model building procedure would be identical i.e.: steps 1 +  2 which are not tied to any particular dataset.
Let's say you did all of the above without having split your data into train-test because you have a small dataset, how do you estimate the generalisation error of the classifier you just created? Can you use the best error you found in the cross validation at step 2 ?
**No**, the first big problem is in step 1 where you use **all the data** to select the features to use. Therefore even when you do the cross validation in step 2, the features will already have seen and remember some information present in the test fold at every cross validation run. The result will be an **overly optimistic** estimate of the test error and this is called **feature selection bias**. To account for this in your estimation you would need to put the feature selection step inside the cross validation loop of step 2.
Ok, now are we good? Is the best error found in the cross validation with feature selection step inside the loop a fair estimate of the generalisation error?
**In theory the answer is still no**, the problem is that your hyper parameters have been chosen to minimise the cross validation error on the **specific dataset** at your disposal, so in a certain sense you are fitting the hyper parameters to your data with the risk of over-fitting them , and this is called **model selection bias**.  But is this a concern in practice? It depends by the specific application: it is likely to become more severe, as overfitting in training, when dataset is small and the **number of hyper parameters** to be tuned is relatively large. To account for this when estimating the generalisation error you would apply a nested cross validation as you described, that would then give you a correct estimate of your generalisation error.
Finally to answer your last question, after having a fair estimate of your “model building procedure” generalisation error with a nested cross validation, you would simply apply the procedure (step 1+2) to your entire dataset obtaining a model with a fixed set of feature and set hyper parameters values, but keeping in mind that the error we expect this model to have on unseen data **is the nested cross validation estimate**.

Comment: The hyperparameters may overfit the model inside the training data but this is not a problem because this model is later used with the validation data.