# How to split dataset for model selection and tuning

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, hyperparameter

I have read as many questions as I could on model selection, cross validation, and hyperparameter tuning and I am still confused on how to partition a dataset for the full training/tuning process.

The scenario: I have 100,000 training instances and I need to pick between 3 competing models (say random forest, ridge, and SVR). I also need to tune the hyperparameters of the selected model. Here is how I *think* the process should look.

Step 1: Split the data into 80,000 training and 20,000 test sets.

Step 2: Using cross validation, train and evaluate the performance of each model on the 80,000 training set (e.g. using 10 fold cv I would be training on 72,000 and testing against 8,000 10 times).

Step 3: Use the 20,000 test set to see how well the models generalize to unseen data, and pick a winner (say ridge).

Step 4: **Go back to** the 80,000 training data and use cross validation to re-train the model and tune the ridge alpha level.

Step 5: Test the tuned model on the 20,000 test set.

Step 6: Train tuned model on full dataset before putting into production.

Is this approach *generally* correct? I know that this example skimps on technical details, but I am wondering specifically about the partitioning of the dataset for selecting and tuning.

If this is not correct, please provide the steps and numeric splits that you would use in this scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also been crawling these threads on this topic.

> Step 1: Split the data into 80,000 training and 20,000 test sets.
>
> Step 2: Using cross validation, train and evaluate the performance of
>   each model on the 80,000 training set (e.g. using 10 fold cv I would
>   be training on 72,000 and testing against 8,000 10 times).

Ok up to this point!

> Step 3: Use the 20,000 test set to see how well the models generalize
>   to unseen data, and pick a winner (say ridge).

Either do this on a portion of the training set that was not used to tune parameters, or implement nested cross validation in your training set (e.g., use 3/4 of each fold to train and 1/4 to select among RF, logistic regression, etc).

> Step 4: Go back to the 80,000 training data and use cross validation
>   to re-train the model and tune the ridge alpha level.
>
> Step 5: Test the tuned model on the 20,000 test set.

This would not be a valid estimate of the error as you've already used this data to choose one of the three RF, LR, etc..

> Step 6: Train tuned model on full dataset before putting into
>   production.

Tuning the model should be considered a step in the training process.

---

Say you have 2 models: RF with param NE = 100, 200; LR with param C = 0.1, 0.2.

You have 2 options (you can mix and match them as long as you adhere to the basic principle: *if you use data to make a decision, don't use that same data to evaluate*):

**A**

- Step 1. Split all data into `train_validate` and `test`. Put test in a vault.
- Step 2. Split `train_validate` into `train` and `validate`.
- Step 3. Train 2 RF on `train` with param NE = 100 and 200. Train 2 LR on `train` with param C=0.1 and 0.2. Try all four models on the `validate`. Choose the model `model_se` with the smallest error. This is your "**modeling process**".
- Step 4. Unlock the vault and test `model_se` (as is) on `test` to get some error.  This error (one number) will be expected error on unseen data.

(It appears you have many observations. There is no hard rule for this that I know of, but if your classes are balanced ***A*** might be most reasonable).

**B**

- Convert step 1 into an (outer) loop.  If you use 7 fold you will have
  7 `train_validates` and 7 `tests`.
- Convert step 2 and 4 into an (inner) loop. If you use 5 fold you will
  then 5 times create a `train` on which you will test the 4 models and
  then 5 times see which is best on `validate`.  Take the model
  `model_ba` with best average performance over folds.
- Test `model_ba` on the test set (in the outer fold) each time (each
  one will be a different model).  Since within each outer loop you
  have an estimate of error, you will have 7 estimates errors.  The
  average of these errors is `E` and the variance `V`.
- Rerun the modeling process Steps 2 and 3 from scratch on the entire
  dataset.  Eg, take 100% of the data and run step 2 to 4 (use the same
  train:validate split ratios or **5** fold CV that you used there).
  You will return some model `M`.  You can expect performance `E` from 
  model `M` on unseen data. The variance `V` unfortunately
  cannot be used to construct a 95% confidence interval (Bengio, 2004).

**B** is also known as 'nested cross validation,' but it is actually just plain cross validation of an entire modeling process (that involves tuning both parameters and hyperparameters or considering hyperparameters to be parameters and just tuning parameters ([see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244907/how-to-get-hyper-parameters-in-nested-cross-validation))). If you choose, **B**, it is worth running multiple iterations of **B** to see the variance of the entire process.

Other methods such as bootstrap may be preferable to cross validation. I have not had time to work out the details of why this is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am following it all until the final part B step "Rerun the modeling process step 2 to 4 from scratch on the entire dataset." Am I running this on all 4 models again? Or only on the winner from the 7 loops? If I am running on all 4 models, why? If not, which one am I using? Also, what if I have different `model_ba` for the 7 loops? Eg loop 1 the RF 100 wins then the LR 0.1 wins loop 2, how can I average these 7 errors `E`?

Comment: You run the entire ***modeling process*** on the full dataset to get your final model. So, you split the full dataset into train and validate and then you train models 1, 2, 3, and 4 on the training set.  You then select the model that performs best on the validation set.  That is your final model---the product of your modeling process.  The models that you generate throughout (eg, in folds 1-7) you might not even save--they are not to be used but to evaluate your process.

Comment: If you have a different `model_ba`, that's ok---they will each give some error. (In regular cross validation, your parameters are not necessarily all identical for every fold; the same applies here). When there is really high variance, that might be an issue.  However, as long as you repeat your whole modeling process=fit parameters+fit hyperparameters+select algorithm it will be an honest estimate of your error.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is imbalanced then you can do the stratified splitting because then it is better to maintain the ratio of different classes of response variable otherwise you can do random splitting of the dataset into training and testing set. On the training set for each of the three model you mentioned you can apply GridSearchCV for tuning the parameters and then test it on the testing set.
In the GridSearchCv you can feed different values of different model's parameters and it will give you the best estimator.
Moreover, I won't suggest you to do the sixth step as we have used a portion of that data in building the model.