# If k-fold cross validation is not for model selection, then how do I know which instance to use?

Tags: neural-networks, matlab

I have a dataset of roughly 1000 subjects' data and their labels. The ultimate goal is to build a neural network which can classify the data as either 0 or 1. My current strategy is to do 10-fold CV, wherein I take a different 10% of the data for testing while training on the remaining 90% (repeated many times). There are many hyperparameters (hidden layer size, net type, etc) which I am optimizing based on the average accuracy of the 10-folds. So at the end of this, I've obtained the best hyperparameters to get the highest average accuracy.

When it is time to actually use this classifier on new data, which model do I use? If my training set is now those 1000 datapoints, then my previously optimized hyperparameters are no longer optimal for that training set.

I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of k-fold, but if not then how do I go about doing this (designing a classifier with labels to be used on unlabeled data in the future)?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your concern is that you've tuned your hyperparameters for a training set of size 900.  But you're eventually going to be using a training set of size 1000, when you retrain a single model on all your data.  That's the way it goes.  Yes, perhaps you could do better with slightly different hyperparameter settings on the larger training set, but I don't know a straightforward way to predict what hyperparameter settings would be better with the larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Re-train the model (including HP) on the **full** dataset, and use that on new data.  *That* model is the one for which your cross validation performance estimates hold.  For details see [Model selection and cross-validation: The right way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64991/model-selection-and-cross-validation-the-right-way/72324).

**Note:** there isn’t a question of which HP set is best (eg say you got $\lambda=7$ in one of your folds and $\lambda=8$ in another and are worried that neither will be optimal for the model trained on the full dataset); you start from scratch and find a *new* $\lambda$ for the full dataset.  Hence you are cross validating a modeling process that involves both training parameters AND hyper parameters. You do NOT take one of the $\lambda=\{7,8\}$, fix it, and train your (non hyper) parameters alone on the full dataset.  That’s not the process you’ve cross-validated.